# how to remove fromHtml deprecated worning using Annotation

Tags: java, android, deprecation-warning

How to remove deprecated error in an android studio.

```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecated")
    public void setText(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            tv_howTo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        } else {
            tv_howTo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
        }
    }
```

I tried using `@SuppressWarnings("deprecated")` and `@TargetApi(15)` but isn't working. I need to remove the deprecated warning.

See Screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suppress warning using Annotation. Just add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` instead of `@SuppressWarnings("deprecated")`, and you won't see that warning anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `//noinspection deprecation` before statement like this:

```
//noinspection deprecation
tv_howTo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
```

Press Alt + Enter on `fromHtml` and Android Studio will suggest you actions to resolve.